# excel sheet upload to mongo

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, mean-stack

I am using the mean.js stack. I need to upload a Microsoft excel doc (.xls) and parse through the items. With that information I would like to create a new object from a schema to upload to a mongo database. I'm not sure where to even begin.

I have the schema for mongoose made. I really need help with the parsing and then saving to mongo. If there are any guides or suggested node packages, they would be great appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to convert your data to **json**. you can use a npm library like excel-to-json. then once you convert your data you can bulk insert them to mongodb with mongoose via your model.

```
excel2json(configuration, function(err, result) {
if(err) {
  console.error(err);
} else {
  Model.create(result, function(err, docs) {
    if(!err){
      console.log('inserted');
    }  
  });
}
});
```